# flutter how to get dynamic or auto height value

Tags: flutter

I want how to make dynamic or auto height value in a flutter
I have listview and container which contain listview. 
 but if the height of the container is less than the total height of listview the result doesn't be shown in screen.
so if listview's length or height becomes higher Container's height becomes higher this is what I want
 how can I?

```
Container(
  height: 400,
  //auto height need
  child: ListView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5), //gab betwween horizonscroll
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //listview scroll fix
    itemCount: weatherList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
      return SizedBox(
        height: 60,
        child: Card(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                  child: Text(weatherList[i].weekName),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    weatherList[i].weekIcon,
                    Text(weatherList[i].weekTemper),
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                  child: Text(weatherList[i].weekdust),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: Can you add some code you have tried? It will help us better understand your problem.

Comment: Add code snippet that you have tried.

Comment: sorry i added right away

Comment: Do you want the height of the container to be as big as it's content?

Comment: yeah that is exactly what i want

Comment: Why add `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`?

Comment: because the top contain in that code is wrapped by customscroll widget so there is two scrollable widget so i fixed

Comment: You just have to remove the `Container` and it would work as expected.

Comment: I solved the problem with shrinkWrap but thank you for your consistant help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved that ploblem with `shrinkWrap=true` in ListView

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`MediaQuery`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html)

MediaQuery class Establishes a subtree in which media queries resolve to the given data.

For example, to learn the size of the current media (e.g., the window containing your app), you can read the `MediaQueryData.size` property from the `MediaQueryData` returned by `MediaQuery.of`: `MediaQuery.of(context).size`.

Comment: you mean put -----MediaQuery.of(context).size.height ---- in height of Container widget? but it take space more than listview